# CrystalReportViewer Does not show reports

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-viewer

I had made a **CrystalReport** using a stored procedure, when I click on a button to show it in a crystal report viewer, I don't see anything but see message :

> Wait while the document is being processing

Sometimes I don't even see this message. I tried the same code with the same **CrystalReport** in another Form, it works pretty good, but not in the other( Huge Project ).

```
CrystalReport1 cr = new CrystalReport1();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt = GetCmd.GetOrderDetails(123);

cr.SetDataSource(dt);


crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

[image]

Comment: why are you using a datatable cr.SetDataSource(GetCmd.GetOrderDetails(123));

Comment: only to organise my code . 
i did it with no DataTable but nothing new .

Comment: what is the result of GetCmd.GetOrderDetails(123)

Comment: it returns a DataTable ,